How do I avoid the memory leak Chrom is indicating when using DropDown react component from ant design
I build a simple class wrapping Dropdown from ant which is working well, displaying alright and functioning. I do however get a warning in the chrom console when switching to a screen with the dropdown in it (I think the problem may be related to the fact the dropdown is not yet visible in the screen):
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
I am using latest version of React (16.14.0) and a very recent one of Chrom (123.0.6312.86) on Windows 10 enterprise.

My very simple wrapper is:
const MenuTree = (props) => {
    
    const { tree, callback } = props

    const onClick = ({ key }) => { callback(key) };
    
    const subs = Object.keys (tree).filter (text => text !== '').map (header => {return ({label: header, children: tree[header]})})
    const items = tree[""].concat (subs);
    
    return (
        <Dropdown
            menu={{
                items,
                onClick,
            }}>
            <Button onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                <Space>
                    <DownOutlined />
                </Space>
            </Button>
        </Dropdown>
    )
}```

